# Difference in LAN speed on different devices using PLC/PowerLAN

Tags: networking, internet, lan, powerline-networking

I don't know if this is the right place for my question, but I don't know where else to ask for advice...

I have issues with the internet connection on my desktop PC.

**Scenario/Background**

My Gateway is located in the living room. My Desktop is located in my bedroom. Unfortunatley,
I can't just run a LAN cable through the walls. So I bought this: https://www.devolo.de/magic-1-lan. I have a 250 m/bits internet connection

**Problem**

When I connect my PC directly with the gateway (by just running a LAN cable through my apartment), I get the full 250.
When I use the Magic LAN, the speed gets reduced to 40, sometimes even 30 m/bits. This seems to be too much, but I knew
that I will have to accept a reduced connection speed with this solution.

**Approaches/"Troubleshooting"**

Now, here it gets a little weird. When I connect my laptop using a LAN adapter with the same Magic LAN (same socket and same LAN cable),
I get 100 m/bits, which seems to be a more reasonable loss in speed.

I used multiple speedtests on multiple browsers with both my desktop PC and Laptop with the same results.

Did some of you had similar issues in the past? Do you know what the problem could be?

Thanks!

Comment: See my answer https://superuser.com/questions/1704594/slow-network-speed-on-wifi-and-powerline-extender/1704596#1704596

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunatley, the answer was more trivial than expected.

I had two power outlets. On the left one, I had a power strip to which the PC and monitors were connected. On the right power outlet I had the magic link. The solution was to put the power strip into the magic link.

I went from 40 m/bits to 100 m/bits.